# Unable to ssh to virtual machine, yet sshd running and firewall port is open

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vps

I'm testing a VM provider's service, and I'm unable to ssh to the VMs I created yesterday. I am able to get in via their web interface shell. The connection just times out:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection timed out
```

I've rebooted the VM; that didn't work. Via the web shell I've tried the following:

```
ps -e | grep sshd             #daemon is running
sudo ss -lnp | grep sshd      #sshd confirmed listening on port 22 for ipv4+6
ssh -v localhost              #I can login via 127.0.0.1 OK
netstat -tuplen               #firewall is open and listening on tcp 22
```

So then I thought "maybe it's my machine or router?" So I tested ssh to a VM I have with another provider, and that worked fine.

Is there anything else that I can do before destroying the VM instance and rebuilding? It's not a calamity (it's just an Ubuntu template that's been updatedif I have to do this, but given that I'm evaluating switching cloud VPS providers, not being able to resolve this with an adequate explanation is a dealbreaker.

Edit: I rebooted from the web console `shutdown -r now`, and then was able to login via ssh. Rebooting from the VM management webpage interface did not achieve this before when I tried. I still have one more identical VM with the same problem that I can perform tests on if anyone has any ideas to try to identify the root cause.

Edit2: after repeated tries and reboots, sometimes I can ssh in, sometimes not. This seems pretty unreliable and from my (the user's) perspective I'm not doing anything different to cause the change in access. I'll contact the cloud provider for an explanation.

Comment: provider may have firewall of its own. (I am thinking of Amazon), you need to open port using provider configuration tool in addition to your VM's firewall.

Comment: It does have a firewall, but there are no rules at the moment.